# MySQL table structure for config data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I have always used the following table structure for something like config data:

- id(int11) Primary AI
- name(varchar255)
- value(varchar255)

With possible rows like:

- (1) site_name > 'My site'
- (2) admin_email > 'some@email.com'

Although this works, I feel it fails the general purpose of config related data as:

- It can contain multiple entries of the same name>value relationships. I can have multiple 'background-color' entries.
- The table feels bulky as the ID column is unneccesary.

What is the best practise or method to overcome the above, to create a table which can still be indexed and have unique 'name' values but obviously still keep in consideration that other tables may have relationships to certain keys/values in the above table?

Comment: Your `name` should obviously be a unique key, other than that I don't think there's any suggestions I can make.

Comment: If you have two rows with `name = 'duck'`, how do you know whish one to use? You need some kind of identifier, like type of entry or something.

Comment: You can make your "name" column primary key also

Comment: Is it then better to drop `id` as it's not really being used and make `name` primary / unique? Also what performance issues may arise? There is really only so much config data a site can have, would having a varchar column as primary have a performance impact on say max 50 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a unique key for the `name` field. This will prevent double names in the table.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE (name);
```

**HINT:** From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> IGNORE is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how ALTER
>   TABLE works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or
>   if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If IGNORE is not
>   specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors
>   occur. If IGNORE is specified, only one row is used of rows with
>   duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted.
>   Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable
>   value.

Comment: I honestly don't know better or what performance implications it may have (so please correct me if I'm wrong) but is it not then better to make `name` the primary key/unique and drop ID as one would not really do a query according to `id` but rather like (select `value` from `config` where `name`='site_name')?

Comment: @chresse Your second 'edit' is a bit redundant. Adding a `UNIQUE` constraint will always add an index.

Comment: @chresse the only way it can enforce the unique constraint is to make an index of it, so the word index in this instance is completely optional and won't change anything.

Comment: i corrected it. i was a little bit confused of it because the manual had 2 sections for it (with and without adding an index). so i thought it would be the best to describe both.